# @output eventemitter is not working-angular 14

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular14, angular-event-emitter

Hi i want to call parent function via child component and i used eventemitter,
every thing seems fine but my function is not getting called.

this is child component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, forwardRef, HostBinding, Input,Output,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'month-date-picker',
  templateUrl: './month-date-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./month-date-picker.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MonthDatePickerComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class MonthDatePickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

@Output() testfunction : EventEmitter<any>  = new EventEmitter()
 prevent(e){
    this.testfunction.emit(null)
}
```

this is child component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle-split" ngbDropdownToggle (click)="prevent($event)">
      <div class="calendar" aria-hidden="true"></div>
    </button>
```

this is parent component.html

```
 <month-date-picker *ngIf="dmanuyear&& compshow == true" name="manufactureYeardup" [manudata]="dmanuyear" formControlName="manufactureYeardup" (checkdate)="checkdate($event)"  (testfunction)="funcheck($event)">
                        </month-date-picker>
```

this is parent component.ts

```
public funcheck(event):void{
    console.log(event)
    alert("hiiiiii")
  }
```

Comment: `prevent` method is not getting called I guess, could you share a stackblitz with the basic issue replicated and share back on the question?

Comment: sure... i gave an alert in prevent function, its working..!

Comment: Please replicate the issue on this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5iqnrz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yppn6x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmonth-date-picker%2Fmonth-date-picker.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmonth-date-picker%2Fmonth-date-picker.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmonth-date-picker%2Fmonth-date-picker.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

its working in stackblitz , but not in my code same function i called...! may be of angular version?, in stackblitz  its 15 and mine is angular 14 any suggestion

Comment: i figured it out @NarenMurali , thanks! there was a bit confusion , actualy the component was used two times in same page, i was checking the first one, but not the second..!, in that second import they haven't called the respective function, tht was the error... now its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function wasn't called on imported child component!

`<month-date-picker *ngIf="dmanuyear&& compshow == true" name="manufactureYeardup" [manudata]="dmanuyear" formControlName="manufactureYeardup" (checkdate)="checkdate($event)"  (testfunction)="funcheck($event)"> </month-date-picker>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).